# How to efficiently fetch data from one MongoDB collection based on another using Node.js, Mongoose and MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections in my case:
**orders**
and **driverRespons**.

The driver can accept or decline the order, and I save his response in the driverResponse collection.

When the driver loads the order again, I should send them to him without his declined orders, because he already declined them, so why send them to him again

Now I fetch all orders from the orders collection and all data from the driverResponse collection, and then I make a `nested loop or filter` to remove the orders from the orders collection that have already been declined in driverResponse.

But I think there is a better way to do that without a JS filter or nested loop, to improve performance, so can anyone please help me?

driverResponse collection

```
[{
orderId:       677f191e810cu4729de867h,
userId: 987f191e810c19729de860ea,
response: 'DECLINED},
{orderId: 507f191e810c19729de8h061,
userId: 767f191e810c19729de8608q,
response: 'DECLINED},
{orderId: 097f191e810ch6729de865s0,
userId: 5hg6191e810c19729de887u5,
response: 'DECLINED}]
```

orders collection

```
[{_Id: 677f191e810cu4729de867hs,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"},
{_Id: 507f191e810c19729de8h061,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"},
{_Id: 677f191e810cu4729de8gj27,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"},
{_Id: 977f191e810cu4729de86y23,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"}},
{_Id: 607f191e810cu4729de86787,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"},
{_Id: 097f191e810ch6729de865s0,
pickupDate:"2023-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the aggregation to retrieve the data without using nested loop.

Please refer bellow the sample approach

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _Id: String,
  pickupDate: Date,
});

// Define the DriverResponse schema
const driverResponseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  orderId: String,
  userId: String,
  response: String,
});

// Define the Order model
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
// Define the DriverResponse model
const DriverResponse = mongoose.model('DriverResponse', driverResponseSchema);

app.get('/orders', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orders = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'driverresponses',
          localField: '_Id',
          foreignField: 'orderId',
          as: 'response',
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          'response.response': { $ne: 'DECLINED' },
        },
      },
    ]);

    res.json(orders);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handel the error
  }
```